# PowerShell 上で java コマンドが別窓で実行されてしまう

Tags: java, windows, powershell

新しいPCを購入して　Windows 上に JDK をいれてパスを通したんですが

```
javac Test.java
java Test
```

というようなコマンドラインから実行したとき
別のターミナルが起動してしまいます

今までのPCでは

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

となるんですが
新しいPCだと

```
> java -version
```

を実行しただけでも一瞬別窓が出てすぐに閉じてしまって標準出力が残りません
（while loop とかでプログラム実行し続けるようにすると別窓に標準出力がでます）

どちらも 環境は
Windows10
PowerShell 7.0
JDK 1.8.0
です

JDK の問題なのか OS の問題なのか PowerShell の問題なのかわからないので
なぜこういうことがおこるのかわかるかたいらっしゃったら助けていただけないでしょうか
コマンドプロンプトから実行した場合にも同じ現象が発生しています

---

**追記**

新しいほうは

```
Path
E:\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin
JAVA_HOME はありませんでした
```

いままでのほうは

```
Path
D:\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin
JAVA_HOME
D:\Program Files\jdk
```

となっています

---

**さらに追記**

```
> Get-command java

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     java.exe                                           8.0.0.132  E:\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe
```

でパス自体は問題ないようです

```
> E:\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe -version
```

を実行しても同様に別ウインドが起動してしまいます

Comment: 環境変数 pathと設定しているならJAVA_HOMEを見てみたいです。Java関連のPathがちがうかも知れません。

Comment: 環境変数の情報を追記しました。JAVA_HOME がなかったんですがこれが関係してるんでしょうか

Comment: 想像ですが、java.batのようなバッチコマンドがあって悪さしているのかなと思っています。```Get-command java```として、java.exeのsourceは見つかりませんか？　また、フルパスでjava.exeを実行した場合はどうなりますか？

Comment: さらに追記しました

Comment: 管理者権限の問題のようですね。一度Javaをアンインストールしてユーザ権限でインストールしてみるのはどうでしょう。あるいは、Javaのバージョンを最新の16系でインストールしてみるとか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.exe の詳細を旧PCと比較していたところ
古いほうは管理者で実行するにチェックが入ってなかったんですが
なぜか新しくインストールした方には管理者で実行するにチェックが入っていました

ただこのチェックをはずしてみても症状は変わらず

PowerShell の方を管理者権限で実行してそのうえでコマンドをたたくと別窓が出なくなりました

なので別窓が出る原因はOSの実行ユーザの問題のようで
おそらく java のインストールの仕方に問題があったみたいなんですが

旧PCは windows7 で java をいれて 10 にアップグレードして使ってるんですが
今回 10 の状態で java をインストールしたのでそのあたりで違ってるのかもです

もともと個人PCで管理者権限持ってるユーザしか作ってないので
とりあえず PowerShell を管理者権限で実行することにします