# PowerShell 上で日本語が文字化けする

Tags: windows, powershell, 文字化け

[power shell 上で java コマンドが別窓で実行されてしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/75875)

上記の以前質問した内容に関連してると思うんですが
ターミナル出力が文字化けします

ただ何かのコマンド実行中だけ窓のサイズが変わって
その間だけ日本語が表示される謎の挙動をします

動画のほうがわかりやすいと思うのでこんな感じです
https://dotup.org/uploda/dotup.org2538993.mp4

前の質問のときは管理者権限をつけて PowerShell を実行したら治ったんですが
今回は管理者で実行をつけたり消したりしても変わりません

Java と PowerShell 両方インストールし直してみましたが変わりません

utf8 のテキストを cat しても文字化けするので
Java は関係なく PowerShell の問題な気がするんですが
解決方法のわかる方いらっしゃったら助けていただけるとありがたいです

---

[PowerShellの文字コードについて解説！文字化けで困らないための対処法](https://www.fenet.jp/infla/column/engineer/powershell%E3%81%AE%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E8%A7%A3%E8%AA%AC%EF%BC%81%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%8C%96%E3%81%91%E3%81%A7%E5%9B%B0%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA/)

ここに書かれている内容は一通り試してみました
PowerShell の文字列は最初から utf8 になってるようです

```
PS F:> $OutputEncoding.EncodingName
Unicode (UTF-8)
```

Comment: 問題点を切り分けてみましょう。Windows Terminal や ConEmu など別のターミナルを使ってみる (デフォルトのターミナルの問題なのか) 、別の Windows アカウントで再現するか試してみる(PowerShell のカスタマイズ等が悪さをしている？) etc...

Comment: 直接は関係無さそうですし、かえって混乱させるかもしれませんが、こんな記事を見つけましたので参考に。[JavaのUnicode入出力問題を回避する](https://blogs.osdn.jp/2020/05/20/java-unicode.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell7のターミナルのプロパティでフォントを「Cascadia Mono」等にしたところ同様の症状になることを確認しました。
現象の原理は不明ですが、フォントを「ＭＳ ゴシック」にすることで現象は回避できるようです。

ちなみに Windows Terminal では標準で Cascadia Mono が使われていますが、こちらでは現象は再現しないようです。

Comment: 治りました！　ありがとうございます！